# How do I format individual cell types based on column heading?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has a heading in row one and a unit type in row two.  These unit types are values such as $, %.

I would like to apply number formatting and also rounding to the cells.

The code I have below reads the column and applies the formatting to the cell, but I cannot figure out how to round the number.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

```
Sub Format()

Dim lngCol As Long, i As Long
Dim str As String

lngCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To lngCol
    Select Case Cells(2, i)
        Case "$": Columns(i).Style = "Currency"
        Case "%": Columns(i).Style = "Percent"
End Select
Next

End sub
```

Comment: Apply the format(s) you want while recording a macro - look at the resulting code.  Eg: percent with 4 dp is "0.0000%"   Note though this is *display only* - it will not actually round the cell values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, you can adapt it as needed ...

```
Public Sub FormatCellsBasedOnString()
    Dim lngToCol As Long, lngCol As Long, lngToRow As Long

    With Sheet1
        lngToCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For lngCol = 1 To lngToCol
            lngToRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lngCol).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(3, lngCol).Address & ":" & .Cells(lngToRow, lngCol).Address).NumberFormat = .Cells(2, lngCol)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

It uses the number format in the 2nd row of the column to format the cells beneath it.  the options are endless really.  Format a cell to what you want, then go to **Custom** in the cell formatting and use that string to format the cell using that macro concept.

[image]

I hope that makes sense.